# Word problem of probability

Tags: probability

In a group of people, 21% own both phones and computers, 49% own just phones and 7% own just computers. One person is randomly chosen, what are the odds that they own a phone if we know that they own a computer?

Comment: $Pr(phone\mid computer) = \frac{Pr(phone\cap computer)}{Pr(computer)}$  What is the probability of owning a phone and a computer?  What is the probability of owning a computer?  (*remember that to own a computer you either own only a computer or you own a phone and a computer*)

Comment: I struggle with the phone∩computer intersection at the top of the division.

Comment: $Pr(phone\cap computer)$ is in words the probability of owning both a phone and a computer.  Do you know how to find that in the problem statement?

Comment: I just don't know how to calculate it. Could it be P(phone) x P(computer)?

Comment: No.  $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is true **only** when the events are independent, and that is definitely not the case here.  There is no "*calculation*" necessary.  Read the first sentence aloud again.  Focus on what the words are saying.  "*In a group of people, ...*"

Comment: So I divide the phones∩computers by computers? 21/7 = 3

Comment: $7\%$ corresponds to **only** computers, not computers and possibly something else.  Read again my first comment.  "To own a computer one either owns **only** a computer **or** owns a computer *and a phone*"  An answer of $3$ couldn't possibly make sense for a probability anyways as probabilities are always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Imagine 100 people.  21 people own both a phone and a computer, 49 own only a phone and 7 own only a computer.  That is a total of 21+ 49+ 7= 77 (so there are 100- 77= 23 people who own neither a phone nor a computer).  21+ 7= 28 people own a computer and, of those 28, 21 also own a phone.  The probability that a person who owns a computer also owns a phone is 21/28= 3/4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $A$ represent the event that the person owns a cellphone, and let $B$ represent the event that a person owns computers.

Note that it is given that $P(A \cap B) = 0.21, P(A - B) = 0.49$, and $P(B - A) = 0.07$. We then need to find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. However, one can see that $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A-B)$ and similarly $P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(B-A)$. We then have $P(A \cap B) = 0.21$, $P(A) = 0.7$, and $P(B) = 0.28$. By Bayes, we know that $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0.21}{0.28} = 3/4$.

Comment: No, he means $P(B)=0.70$ and he made a mistake in defining what he wants $B$ to represent, $P(B)$ here represents the probability of owning a *phone*, not a computer.  Indeed to own a phone one owns only a phone (0.49) or a phone and a computer (0.21) and the sum of these is $0.49+0.21=0.70$.  If not, then there is a lot of cleanup needing to be done with this answer.

Comment: I will say it again in an attempt to get you to notice the problems with this answer.  You have mixed your $A$'s and $B$'s meanings and probabilities all over the place here.  What is the probability of owning a cellphone?  What is $P(B)$?  What did you say $B$ was?  What did you say $P(B)$ was?

Comment: But the final answer is correct, 0.75?

Comment: So it's not 0.75?